# How to configure many-to-many relationship in JPA

Tags: jpa, many-to-many

I'm trying to setup a many-to-many relationship between the entities customers and categories. However when I query the customers using `SELECT c FROM customer c LEFT JOIN FETCH c.customerCategories` I get an `JSON Binding serialization error jakarta.json.bind.JsonbException: Unable to serialize property 'customerCategories' from nl.project.entities.Customer` error.

I based my code of the [many-to-many relationship article on baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many). The code currently consists of the following files;

## Category

```java
package nl.project.entities;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.List;

@Entity(name = "category")
public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;

    @Column
    private BigDecimal price;

    @Column
    private int content;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<CustomerCategory> customerCategories;

    // Getters and Setters
    // Generated toString() method
}
```

## Customer

```java
package nl.project.entities;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

import java.util.List;

@Entity(name = "customer")
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<CustomerCategory> customerCategories;

    // Getters and Setters
    // Generated toString() method
}
```

## CustomerCategory

```java
package nl.project.entities;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.LocalDate;

@Entity(name = "customer_category")
public class CustomerCategory {
    @EmbeddedId
    private CustomerCategoryKey id;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("customerId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    private Customer customer;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("categoryId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    private Category category;

    @Column
    private BigDecimal price;

    @Column(name = "start_date", columnDefinition = "DATE")
    private LocalDate startDate;

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

## CustomerCategoryKey

```java
package nl.project.entities;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Embeddable;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

@Embeddable
public class CustomerCategoryKey implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "customer_id")
    private Long customerId;

    @Column(name = "category_id")
    private Long categoryId;

    // Getters and Setters

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        CustomerCategoryKey that = (CustomerCategoryKey) o;
        return Objects.equals(customerId, that.customerId) && Objects.equals(categoryId, that.categoryId);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(customerId, categoryId);
    }
}
```

## DebugResource

```java
package nl.project;

import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
import jakarta.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import jakarta.persistence.TypedQuery;
import jakarta.persistence.metamodel.EntityType;
import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import nl.project.entities.Category;
import nl.project.entities.Customer;

import java.util.List;

@Path("/debug")
public class DebugResource {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "InMemoryPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @GET
    @Path("/customers")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Customer> customers() {
        TypedQuery<Customer> query = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM customer c LEFT JOIN FETCH c.customerCategories", Customer.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this docs entry](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/json/bind/annotation/JsonbTransient.html)

In your case, you should probably put `@JsonbTransient` annotation on CustomerCategory's `customer` field and Category's `customerCategories` fields, because they form a circular dependencies.